# Repeat content title how i can fix?

Tags: php

```
<?php if (function_exists('get_highest_score_category')): ?> 
    <?php get_highest_score_category(81); ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

index.php code:

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=5&orderby=date&cat=81'); ?> 
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
<?php if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url')) echo z_taxonomy_image_url(); ?> 
<div class="kOrta1"><div class="oNo">1.</div><div class="oTip"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/metin2kucuk.png" /></div><div class="oServer"> 
<?php if (function_exists('get_highest_score_category')): ?> 
<?php get_highest_score_category(81); ?> 
<?php endif; ?></div><div class="oDurum"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "metin_selectt", true); ?>.png" /></div><div class="oZorluk"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "metin_select", true); ?></div><div class="temizle"></div></div> 
<?php endwhile; ?> 
</div></div></div></div>
```

Example my problem:

[image: Example my problem]

Comment: looks like your image is missing. But still the problem is not really clear, please provide more info

Comment: Please try to make your situation clearer by posting relevant code.

Comment: What does `the_post()` do?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to make sense of the code, this is what I have been able to come up with:

```
<?php
    query_posts('showposts=5&orderby=date&cat=81');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url')) echo z_taxonomy_image_url();
?>
    <div class="kOrta1">
        <div class="oNo">1.</div>
        <div class="oTip">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/metin2kucuk.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="oServer"> 
            <?php
                if (function_exists('get_highest_score_category')):
                    get_highest_score_category(81);
                endif;
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="oDurum">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "metin_selectt", true); ?>.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="oZorluk">
            <?php
                echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "metin_select", true);
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="temizle"></div>
    </div>
<?php
    endwhile;
?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

All I see is a loop to blame. I would guess that something with `have_posts()` and `the_post()` is not working well, causing it repeat the post.